# HTML5 App - Native Browser vs Webview

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm trying to gauge the performance differences between using an HTML5 in the native browser installed on a phone or launching the app in a webview.

Does anybody have any experience regarding that? I've google a bit and i haven't really run into any solid answers.

I'm trying to get realistic expectations for a web app launched in a mobile browser vs packing it up in a phonegap app that uses a webview.

Any links regarding the subject would be very helpful.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would point you to research from 2012 by Huy and vanThanh:

http://wiki.stoa.usp.br/images/7/7e/Mobileapp.pdf

Which boils down to: Native > Hybrid > HTML5

However it should be noted that lots of development has taken place since then. Really you are not going to notice much difference in performance because the runtime is effectively the same. Only your use-case is going to be the real deciding factor.

What you should be focusing on is the delivery. Hybrid Apps offer a different experience in terms of being an installed App with the extra of plugins. Whereas HTML5 in the browser is a simpler construct.

If performance is truly a factor then native apps are the only option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer